# DSLR body without auto focus + auto focus macro extension tube set + lens without having auto focus motor but focusing screw = auto focus?

Tags: autofocus, extension-tubes, nikon-d3000, auto-iso

I've Nikon D3000. It died not have auto focus motor boot in its body. I've a lens having no auto focus motor within it. I saw some auto focus macro lens extension tube. Does that have autofocus motor within each extension? And can I get autofocus facility with the assembly that over mentioned so Far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Extension tubes that offer AF capability simply mean they have contacts that allow for electronic communication between the body and the lens. They do not have autofocus motors in them or add autofocus capability to a body/lens combination that doesn't have it without the extension tubes.

Comment: They also often have "screw through" for mounts/lenses that support it, but the screw drive requires a focus motor in the camera body.

Comment: @user28116, Thank a lot for further clarification! You are so intelligent!